# Утилитой sendmail отправить письмо

Tags: php, sendmail

```
  $fp = popen("/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i", "wb");
  fwrite($fp, "From: our script <eartem56@gmail.com>\n");
  fwrite($fp, "To: eartem56@gmail.com\n");
  fwrite($fp, "Subject: here is myself\n");
  fwrite($fp, "\n");
  fwrite($fp, file_get_contents(__FILE__));

  echo fread($fp);
  pclose($fp);
```

Нужно вручную отправить письмо на почту. Именно только утилитой sendmail.

Судя по комментам нужные заголовки я отправил - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916250/unix-sendmail-change-sender-in-header

Но письмо не приходит. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: В том, что вы пытаетесь заявить, что вы гугл (From: @gmail.com), и вас закономерно шлют в папку спам за враньё?

Comment: @andreymal В спаме всё чисто. Да и если указать :@mail почту, тоже не приходит

Comment: Потому что вы и не mail почто тоже и продолжаете врать в поле From. Обратитесь к администратору вашего почтового сервера за правильным значением поля From.

Comment: from должно быть что-то аля `'noreply@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, а не внешняя почта

Comment: mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); Для установки SSMTP выполните в терминале:

    sudo apt-get install ssmtp

Отредактируем файл-конфигурации:

    sudo gedit /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

Добавим туда следующие строчки, заменяя их на свои данные:

    root=youremailhere@gmail.com
    mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
    AuthUser=yourgmailusername
    AuthPass=yourgmailpassword
    UseSTARTTLS=YES

Comment: @InDevX, а если я через localhost, php.ini настраивать надо? ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] соответственно == 0.0.0.0)